# How can we report to our customers that the orders are closed in our react native app?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, application-shutdown

I am making a react native app to deliver homemade snacks by taking orders the previous day. Whenever I am not available, how can I notify my customers that I couldn't take orders?
There are no push notifications in my app.
Do I have to shutdown my server when I am not available? If so, how to shutdown my server and put a message saying the reason for shutting down?

I am using MongoDB as my server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you using for backend nodejs?

Comment: Yes, using Express for backend Mr. Akhil.

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection which will consist of only 1 document.

Create various static attributes within it for now you could add an attribute availabelToTakeOrders which will be a boolean

At your cartPage API, checkoutPage API just check if availabelToTakeOrders is true if true then do what was done before if false send an error("Not Taking Orders Right Now. Come back tomorrow at 9AM")(You could also save this message in the same collection and send it to FE) and show that error on Front-End

You could also create a websocket and listen to changes on FE for this variable and just disable cart and place order button. Show whether the order place is allowed or not using a banner at homepage.

Comment: OP is using Mongo, so no tables and rows. Also, the check must be performed on the backend, both for security and mantainability reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akhil Nayak for the solution. I will try to make use of this solution using Mongodb. I am new to websockets concept. I should read the concept and work through. Thanks once again.